# Phonegap: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'createDocumentFragment' on call of jquery append

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-plugins

So I'm using jquery and phonegap to build an android app. My problem is that whenever I call my plugin, it won't continue. So I trace the problem (thanks to plenty of try-catch statement) and it appears that $(this).append() has a problem.

Here is my function:

```
(function($) {
     $.fn.myplugin = function (list) {
          $.map(list, function(value, index){
                $current = $("#myid_" + index);
                if($current.length == 0){
                     ...
                }else{
                     ...
                     $appendMe = $( "<li />",{
                          "id" : "mayvar_" + value["myvar"]
                     });
                     //Below is the problematic code
                     $(this).append($appendMe);
                }
          });
     };
})(jQuery);
```

And my usage is(note: the calling of the function below is guaranteed that jquery is already load):

```
var temp = {...};
$("#sample").myplugin(temp);
```

and the html file:

```
...
<ul id="sample"></ul>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the real problem but is just didn't append directly to the $(this)

```
(function($) {
     $.fn.myplugin = function (list) {
          $holder = $(this); //added this
          $.map(list, function(value, index){
                $current = $("#myid_" + index);
                if($current.length == 0){
                     ...
                }else{
                     ...
                     $appendMe = $( "<li />",{
                          "id" : "mayvar_" + value["myvar"]
                     });
                     ...
                     //Below is the problematic code
                     //$(this).append($appendMe); changed to below
                     $holder.append($appendMe);
                }
          });
     };
})(jQuery);
```